# node.js / socket.io: lag and unexplained disconnections

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have built a two player real time video game using node.js and express. The bidirectional communication is handled by socket.io. The game is just a clone of Space Invaders, you move a spaceship left and right and shoot at enemies, nothing graphically or computationally intensive.

The game is working fine locally on my computer. When I test it online (on Heroku), I run in two problems mostly:

- the game is laggy (just moving the spaceship left and right is hardly doable). I'm way under the Heroku memory limit and the web transaction response time of my app is good (under 7ms on average).
- sometimes one player disconnects for no obvious reason (on the client side the game just freezes).

It is my first nodejs/socket.io project so I have no idea if these problems can be solved or if it is the kind of technical problems we can expect and hardly solve at the current state of development of these technologies. I must also confess that I'm still using express version 3.2.6 and socket.io 0.9.6. Are there good reasons to think my problems could be solved by upgrading (knowing I don't have problems locally with the same versions)?

EDIT:

On localhost I get the (good) socket.io logs:

```
debug - authorized
info  - handshake authorized h3KKs0td7dWUV-d7dVPW
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/h3KKs0td7dWUV-d7dVPW
debug - set heartbeat interval for client h3KKs0td7dWUV-d7dVPW
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
debug - emitting heartbeat for client h3KKs0td7dWUV-d7dVPW
debug - websocket writing 2::
debug - set heartbeat timeout for client h3KKs0td7dWUV-d7dVPW
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client h3KKs0td7dWUV-d7dVPW
debug - set heartbeat interval for client h3KKs0td7dWUV-d7dVPW
```

but this is what I get on Heroku:

```
2015-03-12T14:54:59.225532+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: authorized
2015-03-12T14:54:59.228461+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/1/?t=1426172098882" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=bdb2d91f-3332-4b42-861a-373889e595c6 fwd="129.199.31.253" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=209
2015-03-12T14:54:59.299001+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/socket.io/1/websocket/909762909928759556" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=4609b498-cc7d-4f65-8a3c-244332150988 fwd="ip" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-03-12T14:54:59.228290+00:00 app[web.1]: info: handshake authorized 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.296245+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.297418+00:00 app[web.1]: warn: websocket connection invalid
2015-03-12T14:54:59.297983+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: set close timeout for client 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.298944+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.406210+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: set heartbeat interval for client 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.407576+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: cleared close timeout for client 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.296644+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: set heartbeat interval for client 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.297579+00:00 app[web.1]: info: transport end (undefined)
2015-03-12T14:54:59.298643+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: cleared close timeout for client 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.405871+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.406676+00:00 app[web.1]: warn: websocket connection invalid
2015-03-12T14:54:59.406788+00:00 app[web.1]: info: transport end (undefined)
2015-03-12T14:54:59.407212+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: set close timeout for client 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.407731+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:54:59.407046+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/socket.io/1/websocket/909762909928759556" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=75d2c5e5-eac3-4ec0-8774-640892993a6e fwd="ip" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-03-12T14:55:09.394154+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/909762909928759556?t=1426172109066
2015-03-12T14:55:09.395831+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: client authorized for 
2015-03-12T14:55:09.397405+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: xhr-polling writing 1::
2015-03-12T14:55:09.458911+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/909762909928759556?t=1426172109122
2015-03-12T14:55:09.459657+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: discarding transport
2015-03-12T14:55:09.491409+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: xhr-polling received data packet �41�5:::{"name":"player","args":["aaa"]}�25�5:::{"name":"update"}
2015-03-12T14:55:09.394628+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: setting poll timeout
2015-03-12T14:55:09.396896+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: clearing poll timeout
2015-03-12T14:55:09.397721+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: set close timeout for client 909762909928759556
2015-03-12T14:55:09.459456+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: setting poll timeout
2015-03-12T14:55:09.459867+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: cleared close timeout for client 909762909928759556
```

As I don't have a lot of time to fix version-related problems I would prefer to explore solutions that don't require to upgrade, except if you tell me the benefits will be great.

PS: I'll be happy to provide pieces of code but I don't know which ones matter for my problems.

Comment: You can start my just logging send/response times in both client and server.  Also log all connect/disconnect events with socket.io.  And, look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger to see what it reports as roundtrip times to your server for all server-side requests.  FYI, for a simple space invaders game, I'm surprised the server needs to be involved in every interaction.  It seems that much of this could be client-side and only go to the server if there are interactions with other users (which I don't think space invaders had) or to record high scores or verify an actual person playing.

Comment: Some relevant reading: [Using webSockets on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets)

Comment: @jfriend00 it's a modified Space Invaders in which two players play at the same time in the same game, so the players must exchange their positions and shots continuously. I've edited my post and added socket.io logs. Some errors of "websocket connection invalid" show up. There are similar threads about that on Stackoverflow but the solutions involve configuring the server (which I have no access to) or not using websockets, so I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that at work my internet connection go through a proxy, that probably doesn't accept websockets. Socket.io was then reverting to xhr-polling for communication.

Testing from another location than work gave no problems.

You can use websites such as http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test to test whether you're connecting to the internet through a proxy.